# how to replace windows 7 completely and repair grub

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, windows-7

I am trying to install Ubuntu on HP probook 4530s x64 system. There is Windows 7 already installed and I want to remove it.

So I format `C:\` drive and make to partition `\` (sha2) and `swap` (sha4) from it. There is also a partition `sha1` (300mb) for MBR (don't know what is it), I just leave it.

After some time I get `fatal error unable to install grub` and so I choose `partition sha1` when it asks.

Now at boot time there is option to choose windows 7 but not for Ubuntu and Windows is also removed.

I also try to install grub form other answers but no success. How to replace windows completely and where to install grub and what to do with 300mb (MBR)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to fix GRUB, thus getting Ubuntu to boot:

1. Boot into Live CD
2. Start a Terminal session
3. Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install boot-repair && sudo boot-repair`
4. Select the recommended repair
5. Follow the instructions you are given
6. Reboot
7. Profit!